# D3 throws "Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null" on setting .data() to appended element

Tags: d3.js

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

This is from a line that sets `.data()` to an element recently appended by `d3`:

```
const someSet = someSelection.filter('.some:(filter)')

someSet.each((d, i, nodes) => {
  const someElement = d3.select(nodes[i])
  const someChild = someElement.append('g')

  someChild.data(this.data) // <-- This line throws the error
   .enter()
   .append('circle')
   .classed('some-class', true)
})
```

Looking around all I could find is [a source saying they had this error when the element in question hadn't yet been added to the page](https://github.com/metricsgraphics/metrics-graphics/issues/690), but I have confirmed that my element was added to the page at the time this error was thrown.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out I was forgetting to add a new empty selection before adding .data() to the nested element:

```
const someSet = someSelection.filter('.some:(filter)')

someSet.each((d, i, nodes) => {
  const someElement = d3.select(nodes[i])
  const someChild = someElement.append('g')

  someChild.selectAll('circle.some-class') // added empty selection here
   .data(this.data)
   .enter()
   .append('circle')
   .classed('some-class', true)
})
```

---

I've also encountered this error if I do something like create a group, store a reference to the group, attach data and append, then try to attach new data to the *reference to the group (`<g>`)* instead of the *selection of the contents of the group)*. For example this will cause this error:

```
const someObj = {} // or some class etc
const someSet = someSelection.filter('.some:(filter)')

someSet.each((d, i, nodes) => {
  const someElement = d3.select(nodes[i])
  const someChild = someElement.append('g')
  someObj.someChild = someChild

  someChild.selectAll('circle.some-class') // added empty selection here
   .data(this.data)
   .enter()
   .append('circle')
   .classed('some-class', true)
})

// ...do stuff
someObj.someChild.data(newData)
// Error because someObj.someChild is a D3 element, not a D3 selection
```

So, at the end it should be:

```
someObj.someChild.selectAll('circle.some-class').data(newData)
```

...or the stored reference should be to the *selection* that the data is added to.

Comment: In my case, I had `.select()` instead of `.selectAll()`.