# d3 with Vue - this.ownerDocument is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I am trying to integrate d3 charts with Vue.  Using a ref seems to give an error, but that's the way to do it right?

```
<template>
      <div ref="chart"></div>
</template>

const chart = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  
  const chartContainer = d3.select(chart);

  const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
  const width = chartContainer.offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  const height = chartContainer.offsetHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const svg = chartContainer
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",`translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.ownerDocument is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Try d3.selectAll instead of d3.select

If that doesn't work, more tips here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696538/7549483